# How to connect Cassandra and Node application in docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, cassandra, docker-compose

I am trying to connect Cassandra which is inside a docker container, from a Node js application which is also present in another docker container.

My question is What is the best way to do it?

Still now I am able to create both of the container using docker-compose.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Using docker-compose.yml I am able to create two containers up and running. Also I am able to connect cassandra from DBeaver and query it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials on connecting Docker containers. See:

- https://deis.com/blog/2016/connecting-docker-containers-1/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/